# JSF 2.0 AJAX call on click of button failing in IE 7

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, listener

I have a button and on click of it an AJAX call is made to the @ViewScoped bean This works fine in firefox but not on IE . However the same functionality works in the other page both IE and Firefox .So i am clueless as to  whats wrong here .

Here is the code

```
 <h:commandButton id="Search"  value="Search" >
 <f:ajax  execute="Search" render="table"  listener="#{Bean.dosearch}" ></f:ajax> 
 </h:commandButton>
```

When Search button is clicked nothing happens.The listener action method itself is not invoked  .the action method takes AjaxBehaviour event as parameter and returns void .and I couldnot debug too in IE and no error is shown  in browser too. Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Best guess is that it is not the button that is the problem. There is quite a lot of javascript involved and IE7 is not always following all the others.

I'd start by stripping down the page to include just the button to see if still doesn't work. If it does, add bit by bit to find out the culprit (not nice debug but it has helped me before)
If it doesn't work, try changing the execute to run the whole page or whole form.

Comment: Thanks Grekier ..Actually its wrong iD referencing Issue .I figured it out Two components have the same exceute ID .Firefox worked fine but IE got confused ..My Bad its my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Can u show the whole page? The problem may not be in the commandbutton but caused by other reasons.
I find the following post made by BalusC quite help. Your problem could be caused by the 6th point mentioned there. If that doesn't help you maybe you can post the whole page as well as the backing bean here so that we can try to reproduce the problem.

Reasons why methods are not getting called:
[commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: hi Wang  
Actually its wrong iD referencing Issue .I figured it out ..Though the link provided by you was very useful for me .Thanks .will have it for future reference :)

Comment: Glad u found the problem xD